# All done. What grammar is that?

Tags: grammar, zero-copula

what grammar is this?

"All done", "clarification needed", "additional information required".

Isn't it "all is done"? Etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's sometimes called [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, all of those phrases need "is" to make them sentences proper. There are also other ways to make them sentences. For example, "(It) needs clarification." Needless to say, don't use them in a graduate thesis, but they meet the criteria for useful language. They're widely used and accepted, clear, efficient, etc.